# Do condition variable spurious wakeups need to be checked in this reader-writer situation?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, condition-variable

As I understand condition variables, you generally need to check for spurious wakeups. For example, a worker thread might wake up on a condition variable notification without there actually being a job ready to go.

So we do something like this:

```
 condition_variable .wait (lock, [&] () {return jobs.size() > 0;});
 execute_job (jobs.pop());
```

Okay, but now I am inside my `execute_job` function. I have a second condition variable which is offering fairly scheduled access to other reader threads

```
 void execute_job (job & j)
 {
     current_job = & j;

     while (! j.finished ())
     {
         std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock (reader_mutex);

         j.do_some_of_it();

         reader_condition.notify_one ();
         reader_condition.wait (lock);
     }

     current_job = nullptr;
 }
```

The reader thread will occasionally (expecting to not wait for very long)

```
 void inspect_current_job ()
 {
      std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock (reader_mutex);

      if (current_job)
          inspect (current_job);

      reader_condition.notify_one ();
 }
```

Is this code safe and correct, especially considering that I am not checking for spurious wakeups on `reader_mutex`?

Comment: When the `execute_job` function calls `wait`, what is it waiting for? And why are you doing some of the work while holding the lock? And what is the purpose of this arrangement? It seems to make the threads wait for each other for no particular reason. (Your two line example code also executes the job while holding the lock. I hope that's a result of code simplification and not what the real code does.)

Comment: Is your issue this: You have a thread that's doing a lot of work on a shared object but has the possibility to pause that work and allow other threads access to the object if they need it. You want to allow other threads to command that first thread to release the lock on the object so they can briefly access it and then resume that first worker thread. If so, you want a reader/writer lock with reader priority.

Answer (score 0):

Don't design code such that a mutex is held all, or most, of the time. That's what causes your fairness issues.

It sounds like you want a lock that gives one thread priority such that if a priority thread is waiting for the lock, a non-priority thread is stopped. Your thread doing the work should use the non-priority locking function so any waiting readers will stop it.

```
class prio_lock
{
    private:

    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    int locked = 0;
    int waiting_priority = 0;

    public:

    void lock(bool priority)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);

        // wait for all prior priority locks
        while (waiting_priority > 0)
            cv.wait(lk);

        if (priority)
            ++waiting_priority;

        // wait for lock to be unlocked
        while (locked != 0)
            cv.wait(lk);

        if (priority)
            --waiting_priority;

        // take the lock
        locked = 1;
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        locked = 0;
        cv.notify_all();
    }
};
```

Note that even if a non-priority thread holds the lock, a priority thread will have to wait until the current lock holder releases the lock before it can make forward progress. That's a consequence of your design which, I strongly suspect, is not good. Threads shouldn't be holding locks other threads are likely to need while they do lots of real work and whatever in your design requires that should be rethought.

I don't know your full outer design but if the reader thread only needs access to job status, it seems like the writer thread should be able to do most of its real work without access to the job status and should be holding the lock only while it's changing that status, not while it's doing the real work.